# In Haskell, why do i have to use the dollar sign in this code?

Tags: haskell

I'm still trying to crack this code:

```
import Data.Char
groupsOf _ [] = []
groupsOf n xs = 
    take n xs : groupsOf n ( tail xs )

problem_8 x = maximum . map product . groupsOf 5 $ x
main = do t <- readFile "p8.log" 
      let digits = map digitToInt $concat $ lines t
      print $ problem_8 digits
```

In     `problem_8 x = maximum . map product . groupsOf 5 $ x`
why can't it just be groupsOf 5 x ?
is it because x will later be expanded to some other expressions(here it will be: `digits = map digitToInt $concat $ lines t` ) ? is this the so-called lazy(x wont be expanded now, but maybe later) ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Without the `$`, the precedence works out like this:

```
maximum . map product . (groupsOf 5 x)
```

Since `.` (function composition) takes two functions as arguments, and `groupsOf 5 x` cannot return a function, this is an error.

With the `$`, the precedence works out like this:

```
(maximum . map product . groupsOf 5) x
```

This is equivalent (via function composition) to:

```
maximum (map product (groupsOf 5 x))
```

or:

```
maximum $ map product $ groupsOf 5 x
```

(however stringing along `$` like this is considered poor style)

This has nothing to do with laziness, note.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by:Since . (function composition) takes two functions as arguments, ? in ". groupsOf 5", 5 is considered as a function ?

Comment: Anyway, great for pointing out about the fact that the dot is expecting a function, not a list or any data type stuff.

Comment: why is chaining `$` considered bad?

Comment: You can switch from a `f x = a . b . c . d . e $ x` form to `f = a . b . c . d . e` for more easily than if you had to change all the `$`s to `.`s. But mostly it's just style, I think.

Answer (score 9):

You don't *have to* use `$`, in fact, you never *have to* use it.

In your case, the pointless^H^H^H^Hsfree notation suggests itself: Instead of

```
problem_8 x = maximum . map product . groupsOf 5 $ x
```

which is equivalent to:

```
problem_8 x = (maximum . map product . groupsOf 5) x
```

we can leave out the `x` on both sides of the equation:

```
problem_8 = maximum . map product . groupsOf 5
```

Comment: Yay, eta reduction! [hlint](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hlint) is highly recommended for such suggestions.

Comment: There are a few cases where using `$` is the only way to do something: like when you're passing it to a higher order function.

Answer (score 5):

As a bdonlan said, `$` is a [function application](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#function-application) and `.` is [functional composition](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#composition).

Use [hoogle](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%24) to figuring out what some keyword are doing. It also could be helpful to showing function signature and module name where it's from.

Comment: "Function application" makes it sound quite fancy... it's in fact just the identity function, specialized for function types.