# How to use $ for avoiding parenthesis in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Haskell documentation(http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.5.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-36-) states:

> $ has low, right-associative binding precedence, so it sometimes
>   allows parentheses to be omitted; for example:
>
> ```
>  f $ g $ h x  =  f (g (h x))
> ```

Namely,  $ can be substituted with parentheses (around anything appearing AFTER $).

So when I saw an example at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8275081/645703,

```
maximum . map product . groupsOf 5 $ x =  (maximum . map product .
groupsOf 5) x
```

I think it should be: (parentheses is around anything appearing AFTER $)

```
maximum . map product . groupsOf 5 $ x =  maximum . map product .
groupsOf 5 (x)
```

I know I am wrong, but I don't know why.

Comment: Because `$ has low, right-associative binding precedence`. So, in the expression `maximum . map product . groupsOf 5 $ x`, its begin with (.) (infixr 9), then the composite function applied to 5 and last `bigFunction $ x`.

Comment: If it helps, the way to think about Haskell syntax is: parentheses come first, then function applications, then operators, then special forms (let_in, case_of, etc.). Parentheses have unambiguous order. Functions are left-associative: a function eats up the first thing it sees, so `f g h` is `f` eating `g` up immediately and resulting in a function which eats `h` up, as opposed to `f (g h)` where g eats h and f waits patiently to eat the result, as it is contained in a "bun" of parentheses. Operators follow the "infixr, infixl" rules. `$` has lower precedence than `.`, causing your confusion.

Comment: @ChrisDrost, thanks. $ can be substituted with parentheses, but they have quite different precedence, which is really confusing for me.

Comment: Then don't think of it as "substituting parentheses." Take it back to the definition: `a $ b = a b`. In other words, `$` is the operator which takes its left hand side and applies it to the right hand side. The elimination of parentheses is not special to it -- that happens, potentially, for all operators. It's just that this particular operator does something really ubiquitous. The real thing you want to think of is "functions happen first, operators happen after", so that turning a function application from a function into the `$` operator makes it the lowest precedence.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`$` takes whatever function is on the left and applies it to whatever is on the right. In can be defined liked so:

```
expr1 $ expr2 = expr1 expr2
```

Of course, putting parenthesis around any identifier by itself doesn't change anything, so let's do that:

```
expr1 $ expr2 = (expr1) (expr2)
```

And since Haskell is lazy, we can simply substitute the arguments to `$` into the resulting expression:

```
f $ g $ h x = (f) (g $ h x) = (f) ((g) (h x))
```

or

```
maximum . map product . groupsOf 5 $ x = (maximum . map product . groupsOf 5) (x)
```

So, `$` (when fully applied) can be thought of as putting parenthesis around *both* sides of the expression.